# Android Google+ Sign-in orientation handling

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Google+ Sign-in on my app but i'm struggling with handling an orientation change while showing the choose account popup.

If the user changes the orientation of the device, the choose account popup is appearing in duplicate. Does anyone have the same issue? Or am i doing something wrong? I have followed [this steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and if no rotation is made, everything works fine and i'm able to perform the login.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe changing orientation restarts the activity lifecycle, which is why you're seeing problems. You need to save your activity instance and reload it after the orientation change occurs. Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more details.

Comment: I have tried that approach and it didn't work. What seems to be happening is that the GoogleApiClient is not saving the state and keeps popping the choose account dialog. For instance if i have already choosen the account and i'm on the accept permissions dialog, if i rotate the screen, the dialog is handled correctly. Thanks